# Transparent AppBarLayout

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

I'm developing an application where I'd like to have a transparent Toolbar (AppBarLayout), but still see the navigation icon button. Unfortunately, best I can achieve is transparent toolbar that still drops the shadow (elevation).

I have a full screen dialog fragment, see style:

```xml
<style name="FullScreenImageStyle" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>


        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

The layout for the fragment looks like this (only the beginning here):

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Later when initializing the dialog fragment, I set the fullscreen style and the navigation icon's resource id.

The result looks like this. Note the toolbar's shadow on top of the screen:
[image]

Any ideas how to solve the problem, please?

Comment: Simply use app:elevation="0dp" inside "AppBarLayout" to remove the shadow.

Comment: @vishal Tried that already. The whole navigation icon dissapears.

Comment: Don't use app bar layout at all. Use a fullscreen theme and make your own layout.

Comment: Use Direct Toolbar. Remove AppBarLayout.

Comment: Tried using only Toolbar (would make sense), but the navigation icon dissapears. It works if I add `translationZ="2dp"`, but it's quite hacky and still doesn't answer original problem.

Comment: @JakubGruber Has the problem been solved?  Would you share?

Answer (score 17):

Try this ;

```
 android:background="@color/transparent"
 android:elevation="0dp"
 app:elevation="0dp"

<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Comment: It causes even the navigation icon to be invisible.

Comment: @JakubGruber . your xml appearance add to most detail

Comment: I solved that by adding `translationZ="2dp"`, but it's a bit hacky. Thought your solution works

Comment: @JakubGruber glad to have a solution. have a fine day.

Comment: Strange, but on API 27, 28 emulators it didn't help me to avoid shades around the Toolbar.

Answer (score 10):

Use this code

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null">
```

```
appBarLayout.setOutlineProvider(null)
```

Answer (score 5):

In the end I solved that by removing `AppBarLayout`, setting toolbar to transparent background and adding translationZ, thought it's a bit hacky.

Here's the code for reference:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <!-- Some other layouts -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  ...
  android:stateListAnimator="@null"
  ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **AppBarLayout** and directly use **Toolbar**:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:paddingStart="6dp"
     android:paddingEnd="16dp"
     android:translationZ="1dp"
     app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
     app:navigationIcon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

  <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     //your content

  </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It will give you this view:

[image: Transparent Toolbar]

Answer (score -1):

Try this code .. and put your image and your needs. this code in toolbar icon and some text and right side also search icon..

```
  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/MyToolbar"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headerIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_location_black"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                style="@style/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```